# AngularJs - push two scopes into a single scope (not merge)

Tags: angularjs, arrays, foreach

I am trying to amalgamate two scopes into one with a different set of labels. Not sure if this is even possible, but here is my code so far.

```
  .controller('eventsCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', 'getEventType1', 'getEventType2',
    function ($scope, $rootScope, $http, getEventType1, getEventType2) {

        $scope.createData = function () {

            //initialise all the things
            var eventsType1 = [];
            var eventsType1 = [];
            $scope.events1 = [];
            $scope.events2 = [];
            var eventsListArray = [];
            $scope.events = [];

            //fetch the data
            var myEventsType1 = getEventType1.fetch(function (events1) {
                $scope.events1 = events1;
            });

            var myEventsType2 = getEventType2.fetch(function (events2) {
                $scope.events2 = events2;
            });

            var theEvents1 = $scope.events1;
            var theEvents2 = $scope.events2;

            angular.forEach(theEvents1, function (event, event1) {
                count += 1;
                console.log('iteration ' + count);
                eventsListArray.push({
                    event_id: event1.id,
                    event_name: event1.name,
                    event_category: event1.category,
                    event_type: 'Type A',
                    event_date: event1.date
                });
           });

           angular.forEach(theEvents2, function (event, event2) {
                eventsListArray.push({
                    event_id: event2.id,
                    event_name: event2.name,
                    event_category: event2.category,
                    event_type: 'Type B',
                    event_date: event2.date
                });
                //$scope.events.push(event2);
            });

            $scope.events = eventsListArray;
        }

        $scope.createData();
    }])
```

(in reality, event1 and event2 are more different from each other than they appear in this example, and they need to be distinguished from each other)

The data is fetched from the server by two different services.

Comment: Which is exactly your question?

Comment: Are the two `.fetch()` methods doing some type of asynchronous data retrieval? If they are this code will likely never work because `theEvents1` will always be an empty array when the `angular.foreach()` loop is reached.

Comment: @Yvonne Aburrow did you sort out ?

Comment: Thanks Lex and @Angular_10 - I have been off sick since Thursday so will give Angular_10's answer a try now.

Comment: @manzapanza the issue was that my attempt was returning an empty array, as Lex pointed out (sorry, should have stated that). Clearly needed to do what Angular_10 suggested and append the items to the array within each service call, so that the asynchronous nature of the service call didn't result in an empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem statement correctly,you want fetch two different lists from `$http` service call and iterate that two lists and add them to the main scope variable which will have both these lists merged with desired objects.

Then make some changes as mentioned below as `$http` calls are async the moment you try to do  `$scope.events = eventsListArray;` in the `createData()` function the service calls are not yet finished so the result will be empty array.

To avoid this lets keep the iteration part in the service call itself and wait till we get the data and then assign to the main scope variable the whole list.

Change your controller like below this will achieve desired results

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('eventsCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', 'getEventType1', 'getEventType2',
    function($scope, $rootScope, $http, getEventType1, getEventType2) {

        $scope.createData = function() {

            //initialise all the things
            var eventsType1 = [];
            var eventsType2 = [];
            $scope.events1 = [];
            $scope.events2 = [];
            var eventsListArray = [];
            $scope.events = [];

            //fetch the data
            var myEventsType1 = getEventType1.fetch(function(events1) {
                $scope.events1 = events1;
                var theEvents1 = $scope.events1;
                angular.forEach(theEvents1, function(event, event1) {
                    count += 1;
                    console.log('iteration ' + count);
                    eventsListArray.push({
                        event_id: event1.id,
                        event_name: event1.name,
                        event_category: event1.category,
                        event_type: 'Type A',
                        event_date: event1.date
                    });
                });
                $scope.events = eventsListArray; //lets assign to the scope varaible as we dont know which requests complete first..
            });

            var myEventsType2 = getEventType2.fetch(function(events2) {
                $scope.events2 = events2;
                var theEvents2 = $scope.events2;
                angular.forEach(theEvents2, function(event, event2) {
                    eventsListArray.push({
                        event_id: event2.id,
                        event_name: event2.name,
                        event_category: event2.category,
                        event_type: 'Type B',
                        event_date: event2.date
                    });
                });
                $scope.events = eventsListArray;//same as above mentioned reason in the end we will have whole list from both async calls..
            });
        }

        $scope.createData();
    }
])
```

Comment: Yes, you did understand the problem correctly, and your solution is fabulous, and it worked - thank you very much indeed

Comment: Glad it helped you ! Happy coding mate